# Platform specific value converters in Windows Phone

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm a little confused as to the best practice for value converters in Windows Phone.

I have successfully converted all my PCL (shared) value converters in to Native converters, following the guidelines outlined here: https://mvvmcross.com/docs/value-converters

A lot of the time we create Platform specific converters on Android and iOS. For example visibility on Android. If I want create platform specific a value converter to use on Windows Phone only, do I have to do this 2-step process again?

1. Create an MvxValueConverter.
2. Create a Native value converter and add it to the app resources.

Is there a more concise solution for Windows Phone specific converters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule I follow is:

If the converter is to be shared between platforms, I create a `MvxValueConverter` implementation and use the NativeValueConverter wrapper to get it to work in a Windows project.

However, if the converter is platform specific, I simply omit using `MvxValueConverter` as it does not add much value, unless you want to use one of the generic types. In most of those cases I just implement `IValueConverter` and register that in the `Resource.Dictionary`.

So the answer is. You don't **need** to use `MvxValueConverter` and the to native value converter wrapper. It is just a `IValueConverter` implementation in the end.